# 100% Questions Answered

Tags: discussion

This most likely won't last long, but it is nice to see. We need to improve the number of questions and visits, but we have a perfect answer score! Great job, everyone!

Comment: I see it's still 100%, although it must be rounded up, as there are seven questions with no upvoted answers at the time of writing this comment. Good to see, nonetheless!

Comment: We are at 5 now. Thinking that those who have 2000+ scores might consider offering bounties. At money.SE, that gets a bit of attention.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer What is at 5 now?

Comment: Unanswered questions?

Comment: 4 now. Good work.

Comment: We're down to 99%... :(